PowerBI modeling with slowly changing dimension
I'm doing the standard Sales analysis (think AdventureWorks DW), but the twist I'm dealing with is that each of my Products has a recipe (ProductKey, IngredientKey, Weight), but the Ingredient is a slowly changing dimension (because the price changes over time). The "recipe" table is static.
So I could calculate the ingredient cost per unit pretty easily, like this:
Per Unit Cost = SUMX('RecipeDetails',[Ingredient Cost] / RELATED('Product'[Yield]))

My problem is that since the IngredientCost will come from the Purchases table (related to Ingredient), how would I retrieve the price for a given week? (Assuming Purchases is (IngredientKey, DateKey, Units, UnitPurchasePrice) ). Can I use FILTER() to retrieve the cost related to the (IngredientKey, DateKey) in the current evaluation context? or do I have to create new versions of the Recipe (ProductKey, IngredientKey) all the time?

Price shouldn't be in the product table. It belongs to the fact table, not a dimension. Move prices from the ingredient table to the recipe table, and your calculations will be very simple.

Oh, I know that the prices don't belong in the Ingredient table. This is the purchases table: Purchases is (IngredientKey, DateKey, Units, UnitPurchasePrice)  The other price is in the Product table because that's the SALE price, not the buy price.

It doesn't matter what the price is. Just move it to the purchase table. You can have as many types of prices in it as you want.
